# Allocating and deallocating event on a button

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am busy having a problem with allocating a new event to an existing button that was created in the designer.

Now here is the button that was created prior to runtime which is inside the modalpopupexteder5 -

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnClose" Text="Close" OnClick="btnClose_Click" />
```

Here is the codebehind -

```
    protected void btnAddAccount_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        btnClose.Click -= new EventHandler(btnClose_Click);
        btnClose.Click += new EventHandler(btnCancel_Click);
        ModalPopupExtender5.Show();            
    }

    protected void btnCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ModalPopupExtender11.Hide();
    }

    protected void btnClose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ModalPopupExtender5.Hide();

    }
```

So the button in the beginning has the event btnClose_Click hooked up to it. But I want to change it to the btnCancel_Click

But it wont execute the btnCancel_Click. It executes the original btnClose_Click

Any Ideas what could of caused this?

Does this relate to the page life cycle?

**--EDIT--**
I should let you know that the btnAddAccount_Click does get executed.

Basically I don't to create the same modalpopupextender, I want to use the existing one but depending on user selection will determine which eventhandler should be called and in this case the btnAccount_Click has selected the btnCancel_Click to be assigned to the button.

Comment: So are you saying you changed it to `OnClick="btnCancel_Click"` and it still executes `btnClose_Click`? Please ensure the event handler isn't getting added in the code-behind, like `btnClose.Click += new EventHandler(btnClose_Click);`

Comment: Yes that is exactly what is happening. 
MikeSmithDev - "Please ensure the event handler isn't getting added in the code-behind..."
Do you mean that the allocating and deallocating of event handlers shouldn't be used or are you saying should I make sure that the allocating and deallocating of event handlers are taking place?

Answer (score 1):

ASP.NET is not assigning the Click events anywhere for the server side buttons. Those buttons are rendered as plain submit buttons, and the internal code behind is checking the submitted value then based on that it finds the "clicked" button and calls the proper handler.

This means your current logic is leading to a dead end.

Instead of messing with the events, have `btnClose_Click` as the handler, and in there check the currently active/visible popup and hide it.

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure what exactly you are asking, but you can add a `Handles` to your event and so control the events on your buttons.
Something like:

```
protected void btnCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) Handles btnCancel.Click, btnClose.Click
{
    //do stuff 
}
```

Comment: These handlers are present. There is one button that is hooked up to one of the handlers called btnClose_Click this is linked before runtime. Now I want that same button to deallocate the previous handler and add a new handler called btnCancel_Click